# Python re: Regex expression for pattern following 3 letters and comma

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How would one write a regex expression in python re, where the pattern is :
3 english letters followed by a comma

Example:

```
string_var = "AAA, BBB, CCC"  # follows the pattern 
string_var = "AAA, BBBB, CCC, DDD" # does not follow the pattern
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to only check if a string matches, use `^[A-Za-z]{3}, [A-Za-z]{3}, [A-Za-z]{3}$` (https://regexr.com/5i22s). This will be true for "AAA, BBB, CCC", but is not useful for finding matches like in "test asf, cat, dog".

```
^        Start of string
[A-Za-z] Alphabet characters
{3}      3 alphabet characters
,        A comma followed by a space
...
$        End of string
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
^([a-zA-Z]{3},\s){2}[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

or use this with `re.I` flag

```
^([a-z]{3},\s){2}[a-z]{3}$
```